# psql - order alphabetically on either field

Tags: postgresql, psql

Say I have a query like this

```
SELECT "contacts".name, "email_addresses".address 
FROM "contacts" 
LEFT JOIN "email_addresses" ON ("contacts"."id" = "email_addresses"."contact_id") WHERE (("contacts"."account_id" = 1) AND ("public" IS TRUE)) 
ORDER BY "contacts"."name", "email_addresses"."address"
```

Some of the results might have null name fields or null email addresses, I want to order alphabetically on a sort of computed property of display_name that orders by the name if there is one and if not by the email address if there is no name field so I could get results like this:

```
name              | email
====================================
null              | aaron@gmail.com
Ben Jones         | null
Colin Cowan       | zach@gmail.com
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html) function which takes the first non null value of the supplied parameters:

```
order by coalesce("contacts"."name","email_addresses"."address")
```

Comment: yes but that would still order Ben JOnes above aaron@tmail.com.  I'm looking for a way of ordering alphabetically of the combined columns.

Comment: @dagda1 It should put 'aaron@gmail.com' first; and it did when I tried.

Comment: that is not the result I get

Comment: Look at this SQL fiddle using Postgres: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70eb5/1 isn't that the correct result?